# How to use the same custom view with a slightly different design?

Tags: android, architecture, android-xml

My Android `Activity` should have a `Custom View`. I need to define a `Custom View` in the `Activity` XML layout. This `Custom View` should have slightly different layouts and behavior depending on the boolean value in the `Activity`. The behavior is defined both in the `Activity` and in the `Custom View`.

Note: The boolean value is used only once on a `Custom View` creation

I have a few options:

1. Create 2 `Custom Views` with different XML layouts, add them to the `Activity` XML layout, and set visibility of each custom view depending on the boolean value in the `Activity`
2. Create a `Custom View` with 2 different XML layouts, add it to the `Activity` XML layout, and inflate a `Custom View` XML layout after the boolean value is set
3. Create a `Custom View` with an XML layout that contains both layouts inside the `FrameLayout`, add it to the `Activity` XML layout, and set visibility of each custom view depending on the boolean value in the `Activity`

Which is the most idiomatic way of using the same custom view with a slightly different behavior? When other options can come in handy?

Comment: Why not to retreive your `boolean` value from xml when inflating your `Custom View` and change view according to this value?

Comment: @i30mb1 What do you mean by `retrieve your boolean value from xml`? I have a boolean value in the activity. I have edited my question. Please, check